# How do I retain my data in react component when the page is restored

Tags: reactjs, ethereum, solidity, restore, smartcontracts

I'm trying to store my files in IPFS and get the hash value and store them in the smart contract.I want to retain my hash value when the page get's reloaded. But in the below code the certificate files I upload get vanished once the page is reloaded. How can I make it. As I'm new to development I'm unaware of it. Please suggest some ideas. I'll attach my App.js code below.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import web3 from './web3';
import ipfs from './ipfs';
import storehash from './storehash';
import { Button } from 'reactstrap';
import "./App.css";


class App extends Component {
  state = {      
    ipfsHash:null,      
    buffer:'',      
    ethAddress:'',      
    transactionHash:'',      
    txReceipt: ''    
  };


  //Take file input from user
  captureFile =(event) => {event.stopPropagation() 
    event.preventDefault() 
    const file = event.target.files[0] 
    let reader = new window.FileReader() 
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file) 
    reader.onloadend = () => this.convertToBuffer(reader) };


  //Convert the file to buffer to store on IPFS 
    convertToBuffer = async(reader) => {

  //file is converted to a buffer for upload to IPFS        
    const buffer = await Buffer.from(reader.result);   

  //set this buffer-using es6 syntax        
    this.setState({buffer});};

  //ES6 async 
    functiononClick = async () => {try{this.setState({blockNumber:"waiting.."});        
    this.setState({gasUsed:"waiting..."});
    await web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(this.state.transactionHash, (err, txReceipt)=>{          
      console.log(err,txReceipt);          
      this.setState({txReceipt});        
    });      
  }

  catch(error){      
    console.log(error);   
   }}


   onSubmit = async (event) => {      
     event.preventDefault();

     //bring in user's metamask account address      
     const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();   

     //obtain contract address from storehash.js      
     const ethAddress= await storehash.options.address;      
     this.setState({ethAddress});    

     //save document to IPFS,return its hash#, and set hash# to state      
     await ipfs.add(this.state.buffer, (err, ipfsHash) => {        
       console.log(err,ipfsHash);        

       //setState by setting ipfsHash to ipfsHash[0].hash        
       this.setState({ ipfsHash:ipfsHash[0].hash });       
       
       
       // call Ethereum contract method "sendHash" and .send IPFS hash to etheruem contract       
      //return the transaction hash from the ethereum contract        
      storehash.methods.sendhash1(this.state.ipfsHash).send({          
        from: accounts[0]        
      }, 
        (error, transactionHash) => {          
        console.log(transactionHash);          
        this.setState({transactionHash});        
      });  

      storehash.methods.sendhash2(this.state.ipfsHash).send({          
        from: accounts[0]        
      }, 
        (error, transactionHash) => {          
        console.log(transactionHash);          
        this.setState({transactionHash});        
      });  

      storehash.methods.sendhash3(this.state.ipfsHash).send({          
        from: accounts[0]        
      }, 
        (error, transactionHash) => {          
        console.log(transactionHash);          
        this.setState({transactionHash});        
      });  

      storehash.methods.sendhash4(this.state.ipfsHash).send({          
        from: accounts[0]        
      }, 
        (error, transactionHash) => {          
        console.log(transactionHash);          
        this.setState({transactionHash});        
      });  

      

    })    
  };


  render() {
    return (        
    <div className="App">          
    <header className="App-header">  
    <h1>EduDecentro</h1>          
    </header>

    <hr/>
    <grid>          
      <h5> Choose Transcript file  </h5>          
      <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>            
      <input              
      type = "file"              
      onChange = {this.captureFile}            
      />             
      <Button             
      bsStyle="primary"             
      type="submit">             
      Send it             
      </Button> 
      </form>
      <tbody>                 
         <tr>                   
           <td>IPFS Hash</td>                   
            <td> : </td>                    
            <td>{this.state.ipfsHash}</td>                  
            </tr>
      </tbody>
      

      <h5> Choose Certificate-1 file  </h5>          
      <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>            
      <input              
      type = "file"              
      onChange = {this.captureFile}            
      />             
      <Button             
      bsStyle="primary"             
      type="submit">             
      Send it             
      </Button> 
      </form>
      <tbody>                 
         <tr>                   
           <td>IPFS Hash</td>                   
            <td> : </td>                    
            <td>{this.state.ipfshash2}</td>                  
            </tr>
      </tbody>

      <h5> Choose Certificate-2 file  </h5>          
      <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>            
      <input              
      type = "file"              
      onChange = {this.captureFile}            
      />             
      <Button             
      bsStyle="primary"             
      type="submit">             
      Send it             
      </Button> 
      </form>
      <tbody>                 
         <tr>                   
           <td>IPFS Hash</td>                   
            <td> : </td>                    
            <td>{this.state.ipfshash3ash3}</td>                  
            </tr>
      </tbody>

      <h5> Choose Resume file  </h5>          
      <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>            
      <input              
      type = "file"              
      onChange = {this.captureFile}            
      />             
      <Button             
      bsStyle="primary"             
      type="submit">             
      Send it             
      </Button> 
      </form>
      <tbody>                 
         <tr>                   
           <td>IPFS Hash</td>                   
            <td> : </td>                    
            <td>{this.state.ipfshash4}</td>                  
            </tr>
      </tbody>


       
      <hr/> 
      <Button             
      bsStyle="primary"             
      type="submit">             
      LOGOUT            
      </Button>
      </grid>     
    </div>      
   );    
}}

 export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

2 possible ways,

1. Integrate **redux** with your project and use **redux persis**t to keep data available with refresh.
2. Try to cache your data in **session storage** which remains the same with refresh and gets vanished with tab's closing. You may consider local storage, too.

You can read [this](https://www.robinwieruch.de/local-storage-react) article.